# Flutter ListTile with Radio Button 3 in one row

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to add 3 radio buttons with titles in a row in flutter using Radio Button ad ListTile but the title of each radio button is overflowing and is appearing in two lines. How can I make it appear in one line?

Here is Image

[image]

Here is the code I am using for displaying 3 tiles.

```
             Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 5),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text("Gender",
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19),),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Expanded(
                                  child:ListTile(
                                    title: const Text('Female'),
                                    leading: Radio(
                                      fillColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => Color(0XFFB63728)),
                                      value: Gender.female,
                                      groupValue: _gen,
                                      onChanged: (Gender? value) {
                                        setState(() {
                                          _gen = value;
                                        });
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                  child: ListTile(

                                    title: const Text('Male'),
                                    leading: Radio(
                                      fillColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => Color(0XFFB63728)),
                                      value: Gender.male,
                                      groupValue: _gen,
                                      onChanged: (Gender? value) {
                                        setState(() {
                                          _gen = value;
                                        });
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ),),
                                Expanded(
                                  child:ListTile(
                                    title: const Text('Other'),
                                    leading: Radio(
                                      fillColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => Color(0XFFB63728)),
                                      value: Gender.other,
                                      groupValue: _gen,
                                      onChanged: (Gender? value) {
                                        setState(() {
                                          _gen = value;
                                        });
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),

                              ],
                            )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `contentPadding` property inside `ListTile` :

```
ListTile(
       contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0)
)
```

`contentPadding` set `0` remove extra space between `leading` and `title`.

For more information : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile/contentPadding.html